# UML to java or c# tool?

Tags: c#, java, uml

Is there any tool that can convert UML into Java or C#?

Comment: What tool are you using to draw the UML? Most UML tools support code generation....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Argo UML**

http://argouml.tigris.org/

http://www.argouml-users.net/index.php?title=Modules

Can export to Java, C#, C++ and others.
Open source.

**Enterprise Architect** if you want a non-open source tool.

http://www.sparxsystems.com/

Comment: Argo UML still doesn't support UML 2.x

Comment: Stook is correct - however it is actively being developed at the moment. http://argouml.tigris.org/wiki/UML_2.x_support - and this wasn't stated in the question.

Answer (score 2):

For Java there are quite a few, where I think **[AndroMDA](http://www.andromda.org/index.php)** is among the more well known. In terms of powerfulness though, it seems **[OpenMDX](http://www.openmdx.org/#HOME)** takes the lead, seemingly providing more powerfulness than others in terms of persistance handling etc. On their webpage it is told that OpenMDX differs from typical MDA frameworks in that it *"uses models to directly drive the runtime behavior of operational systems"*.

For C#, there is nothing coming even close to [ECO](http://capableobjects.com/ProductsServices_ECO.aspx) (Enterprise Core Objects), by the team behind the UML/MDA part of Borland's Delphi Architect product (before Delphi was sold to CodeGear). From their product web page:

> ECO will then generate the database
>   schema, the code for the domain
>   classes, and the information for
>   mapping the classes to the database
>   tables.
>
> And better yet, when you change your
>   model, ECO will merge the changes into
>   your code, and update your database
>   schema while preserving your precious
>   data. A feature we refer to as
>   i>Database Evolution

This hints about the powerfulness of it. The main consequence is that with these features you will be able to work with your problem solving at the UML-modelling level (since you can continuously update your codebase with a changed model even after you've added your custom code, without needing to update all the relational mapping etc, since it is taken care of automagically), which - with clever modelling - can reduce the amount of coding needed drastically.

Answer (score 0):

For open source, have a look at [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/). There are also several commercial tools available, e.g. [Rational Rose](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/developer/rose/).

Comment: All i want to tick but i can only tick one

Comment: @UMLfans001: That does not stop you from up-voting!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to others mentioned: [Umbrello UML Modeller](http://uml.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The answer is that the translation requested can be performed by Umbrello - the question asks for specific tools, this is one - what more is there to say?.  If you think that more than that can be usefully added, go ahead.  The answer has stood two years before any comment, I think I;ll let it stand, especially since teh question has been closed all this time.